# Apache Server 2.2.34 x64 - Using mod_wsgi - Running Python Scripts - Cannot Use WSGIDaemonProcess Daemon Mode

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to create an Apache Server to service an existing Python script to return R statistics. Outside of Apache, my scripts run great but can take several minutes to run. Inside of Apache, the script runs 50% of the time and often slowly.

I am trying to use the WSGIDaemonProcess directive in httpd.conf but Apache refuses to start if I do that, so I assume I am stuck in embedded mode.

I am not defining a virtual server, and I declare everything in httpd.conf.

```
ServerRoot "e:/Apache2"
Listen 80
LoadFile "e:/program files/python36/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "e:/program files/python36/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "e:/program files/python36"
#
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName x.y.z.d:80
DocumentRoot "e:/Apache2/htdocs"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "e:/Apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.py
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel crit

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "e:/Apache2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
</IfModule>

<Directory "e:/Apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "E:/wsgi_app/wsgi_app.py"
<Directory "E:/wsgi_app">
<Files wsgi_app.py>
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I can move this to Linux if that is easier.

Thanks,

Lou

Comment: a service under another service ? i got python server and 50us (microseconds) delay.  The reason why the Python language (in Web applications) is fast is that there is no external dependency. If you try on Apache, your delay will be at least as much as the main service (Apache) delay.  The method you use will never be performance. The Python application (non-standalone) that is connected to another service does not work in performance.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about fast, just reliable and offering the graphs as a web service. I would just be happy to get Apache and wsgi running in daemon mode, That's what I cannot seem to get running.

Comment: Okay, I see this now in article https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/HelpOnInstalling/ApacheWithModWSGI - "Windows users: daemon mode does not work under Windows, and so does not apply". I guess I am out of luck unless It port this to Linux.